# How to open PHP socket onto some URL? (like www.ex.com:8080/mySock/)

Tags: php, url, sockets

How to open PHP socket onto some URL? (like www.ex.com:8080/mySock/)

I want to send user to a user Chart Room 1  if ho goes to www.ex.com:8080/mySock/Chart1 and www.ex.com:8080/mySock/Chart2 to some other chart room if he goes into another (live php multy useres chart on sockets (Flash backend))

Comment: What's a "PHP socket"? Most of the kinds of sockets I know don't communicate with URLs, but network hosts.

Comment: Ole: I fear that you have a very distorted view of how sockets actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($socket, gethostbyname("www.ex.com"), 8080);
```

but are you sure you actually want a direct socket? If you clarify what you're actually doing, odds are PHP has some better way to accomplish it

Comment: I want to send user to a user Chart Room 1  if ho goes to www.ex.com:8080/mySock/Chart1 and www.ex.com:8080/mySock/Chart2 if he goes into another (live php useres chart on sockets)